# Installed Nvidia Drivers, but can't adjust brightness in the Settings

Tags: drivers, nvidia, brightness

I recently dual booted Ubuntu 14.04 and installed the drivers for my GPU (Nvidia GTX 960). For some reason, I am unable to control the brightness using the slider in the Brightness & Lock settings.

How can I fix this issue? Google has done nothing so far. Everything I've come across is about keyboard shortcuts providing brightness control.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories work fine.
But as you have an issue with the quite new GTX 960 graphics chip,
you can install the latest official NVIDIA drivers as an alternative.
NVIDIA has fixed bugs and improved the drivers for new cards.

Step 1 : Remove the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

Step 2 : Install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Even after doing this I am unable to move teh slider and adjust the brightness.

Comment: @FrakkinShip Hi! It is not possible to adjust the rightness that way I am afraid since most of the driver's code is a proprietary one, therefore neither Ubuntu devs have the possibility or chance to implement this feature  nor nvidia devs have the will to do so.