# My screen brightness is not changing

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, lenovo, brightness

I have a [Lenovo Ideapad Y740](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y740-15ichg?linkTrack=Homepage%3ABody_Search%20Products&searchType=3&keyWordSearch=Legion%20Y740-15ICHg%20Laptop%20(Lenovo)) with an RTX 2060 card. I installed a fresh new version of Ubuntu 18.04, dual booting with Windows. I am trying to change my brightness which is stuck at a very high value right now. When I go to /sys/class/backlight I find only acpi_video0. I tried changing the brightness from inside that but still no change. I am very new to Ubuntu and Linux, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I used google "ubuntu nvidia stuck on high brightness" to search on questions and answers like this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/728575/installed-nvidia-drivers-but-cant-adjust-brightness-in-the-settings